# Get time Android

Tags: android, timepicker

I use Time Picker and i Want take value of hour and minute after push a button, i've make this code but the app shutdown after I push it.. I don't know where is the error.

```
final TimePicker tp = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.tp);



    Button b3 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.b3);
    b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int hour = tp.getCurrentHour();
            int minute = tp.getCurrentMinute();
            String a =Integer.toString(hour);
            String b = Integer.toString(minute);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, a, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, b, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you getting an error in your console log?

Comment: add error logs.

Comment: We don't know where the error is either unless you tell us what the problem you see is. Showing two toasts over one another probably doesn't help see the problem, though

Comment: You should add error logs so we can give you  a hand.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `TimePickerDialog` with a `DialogFragment` For a working example you can check out a test app I have here:
https://github.com/agramian/android-test-app/blob/master/AndroidTest/app/src/main/java/com/abtingramian/android/androidtest/feature/calendar/CalendarLayout.java